# I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob

(ionic 5 app won't load admob ads when run it for test on android using capacitor (ionic capacitor run android) or on real device)

FYI: i've already added the metadata containing ads id to androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this plugin from Capacitor comunity :https://github.com/rahadur/capacitor-admob
It works perfectly for your needs.

Comment: be more specific bro, send which plugin are you using and send some code.

Comment: here is some dependencies that i use
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.24.1",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.27.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",

Comment: https://github.com/rahadur/capacitor-admob use this plugin not from cordova.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, i've changed admob from cordova to capacitor and it worked fine for me

Comment: Not problem bro, I recomend to implement more capacitor plugins instead of deprecated cordova.